# make circle using 360 div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, geometry

write a program to make a circle using 360 divs arranged to make circle using the javascript.
Hint:use absolute position and looping and don't use jquery.

Comment: use css, border-radius: 50% and you are done

Comment: @Tick20 lol exactly. Mikhael you should try something and then post it if you are stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do is,

Use the following CSS to do this

```
.div{
  border-radius:50%
}
```

Comment: I think the OP needed to use 360 doc elements. Although your answer is definitely what I would do! :)

Comment: The other way is you can use

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>